# How do I use unicode_escape correctly?

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, escaping

I need to add an additional `\` to escape some characters. For instance, `BC \ BS` needs to become `BC \\ BS`. The following line solves the issue:

```
txt.encode('unicode_escape').replace("'", "\\'")
```

However, it messes up other characters. For example, `^@?` becomes `\x00?`. in such a situation, I will need to remove `\x00` as a subsequent step but other characters might show up.

What is the most Pythonic way to add the escape character to set of characters such as `\`,`\t`,`\n` etc. without causing other characters to break? I have tried using `translate` but ran into issues as the character size of `\\t` is unequal to `\t`.

Comment: Is this source text that is going to go to a language parser ?

Comment: Are you planning to use this in a regular expression? If so the `escape` function in the `re` module may do what you need.

Comment: Find: `(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)([tnrb]|\\(?!\\))` replace `$1\\$2` Because, it could already be escaped. It's imperative to know the difference.

Comment: @TripleD `re.escape` doesn't do it. It escapes a bunch of chars but the output can't be read by the reader I'm using. A number of  `\`s cause issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to escape certain characters in text strings, raw text strings, or byte strings? What is the full set of characters you need to escape? If it's text, then there is no need to encode it first...Some things you can try:

```
test = "Please escape this: ' and this \n"
for char in ["'","\n"]:
     test = test.replace(char, f"\{char}")

complicated_test = "This \tstring \n is \ full of ' things to \t escape"
re.escape(complicated_test)
```